# Ajax get request with Django

Tags: ajax, django, jquery

I try to implement an ajax request in my django app to get the number of spectators of a flash video recorder I implemented in my app. This number is in an xml file.

Here the js I used did in my template:

```
    var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    var id = url[2];     // The id of my video is www.mysite/video/ID.com

    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://myxmlfiles",
            success: parseXml
        });
    }, 2000);

    function parseXml(xml){
        $(xml).find("user").each(function() {

            if($(this).attr("id") === id) {
                $(".DubScore").html($(this).attr("count"))
            }

        });
    }
```

And in my html:

```
      <div class="DubScore"> </div>
```

The xml file renders:

```
   <streams>
   <user id="3" count="1"/>
   </streams>
```

The problem is nothing appears. I really don't know what I did wrong.

Any advice would be great,

EDIT:
   When I run my js console, I can see the number of spectators, as I wanted. So the only problem is that it doesn't display this number into my div. The problem is between the js and the html. If you have any idea on how to fix it, it would be great. Thanks

Comment: use dajaxice dajax libs.

Comment: you mean I have to import it?

Comment: What's the error message on the javascript console of the browser?

Comment: I have "The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating". It's the only error I get, and it's not related to my initial problem.

Comment: I do have something in my js console. I number of spectators is displayed every 2 seconds, as I asked. So the problem is just that it's not displayed in my div. I don't know what is the problem